# Authenticate client to Squid Proxy with Negotiate- Kerberos

Tags: security, ldap, authentication, squid, kerberos

My client machine is communicating with squid proxy by Basic Authentication mode.
In Basic Authentication client is passing an authentication header like below to proxy

```
{+add-header{Proxy-Authorization: Basic dGNvZTE6dGNvZTE=}}
```

Since the basic authentication is weak i have to move my authentication to Negotiate / Kerberos .

Can anybody suggest me how client will communicate with proxy ?
What are all the information i have to pass?
Proxy-Authorization header is required or not? if required what i should pass as param ?
Note : I am not familiar with these configurations , most of the sources in the internet are not taking me in the right direction.

Recently i have read a thread 
[The Story of secure user-authentication in squid](https://serverfault.com/questions/151672/the-story-of-secure-user-authentication-in-squid?rq=1)
In that i read a comment by @gravity , @gravity mentioned he has implemented that already. Please suggest me a solution.

Comment: I think the answer you want is basically that found in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4265975/authentication-issues-with-www-authenticate-negotiate : there is no equivalent header to the one you show for Negotiate.

Answer (score 2):

you need to use the follow [squid docs on kerberos](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/ConfigExamples/Authenticate/Kerberos)

If you do not have to deal with an AD kerberos realm, the steps could be somewhat different, but the gist of it will be the same.

Comment: also https://www.freeipa.org/page/Squid_Integration_with_FreeIPA_using_Single_Sign_On